# htaccess rewrite URL php parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a specific PHP file GET parameter but cant seem to get things to work.

I want to rewrite `http://www.example.com/meeting.php?ref=y0fpjXrrGP` so it is `http://www.example.com/meeting/y0fpjXrrGP`

What am I mising on the below?  Note I am using WordPress so adding to the existing htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^meeting/(.*)$ meeting.php?ref=$1
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options -Indexes
```

Adding `RewriteRule ^meeting/(.*)$ meeting.php?ref=$1` does not seem to work at all.

Comment: It wiil not because every non file name request is being rewriting to index.php i suggest you to go wordpress way for rewriting and add tag of wordpress in your question to get more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^meeting/([^/]*)$ /meeting.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `http://www.example.com/meeting/y0fpjXrrGP`

Make sure you clear your cache when testing this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add that to .htaccess, if your URL is inside your Wordpress, you need to add them to the rewrite URL

Check this:
[How to create custom URL routes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes)

Hope it helps.